# Why does ping to google.com or 8.8.8.8 fails

Tags: networking, dns, ping, yum, centos-6

I am using Cent OS 6.4 and it is in a official lab.

`ping google.com` gives the below output and hangs:

```
[root@LAB1 ~]# ping google.com  
PING google.com (74.125.236.195) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

`ping 8.8.8.8` also yields the same result. I am able to access internet from browser(Mozilla). Is there a problem with the network settings or configuration?

Below is the output from `traceroute - n 8.8.8.8`

```
[root@LAB1 ~]# traceroute -n 8.8.8.8 traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
1 * * *
2 * * *
3 * * *
4 * * *
5 * * *
6 *^Z
```

Below is the output from `route -n` if it helps

```
[root@LAB1 ~]# route -n  
Kernel IP routing table  
Destination Gateway Genmask Flags Metric Ref Use Iface  
192.168.1.0 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.0 U 1 0 0 eth0  
0.0.0.0 192.168.1.1 0.0.0.0 UG 0 0 0 eth0
```

The main reason for me to try the above ping is to resolve an yum update command that fails to resolve the mirror sites...

As I am new to networking, I am not able to identify the issue. Any help here is much appreciated...

Comment: Try pinging your default gateway. If you can reach that then your PC/configuration is probably fine and something further on is blocking ICMP echo requests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many corporate firewalls block `ICMP` - which is the protocol is used by `ping` utility.

Better solution for this is to try `TCP` connection to `google.com:80`.

Easiest way to check for basic internet connectivity in shell script is utility `nc` (it should be easily available on most Linux systems):

```
nc -w 3 -z google.com 80
echo $?
```

This means check if port `80` on `google.com` is open, and timeout after `3` seconds. If connection was successful, it will print `0`, and if it failed, it will print `1`.

---

If you want to check internet connectivity *without* checking DNS (which could be broken in itself), you can use Google's preferred DNS server `8.8.8.8`, but the only port that it has open is `53` (aka `domain`):

```
nc -w 3 -z 8.8.8.8 53
echo $?
```

However, port `53` can be also blocked by your corporate firewall (not common, but possible). Ports `80` and `443`, on other hand, are almost never firewalled.

Comment: Thanks mvp, but unfortunately, i dont have nc available here. But I understand that they have blocked ICMP which is why ping is not working. I have accepted your answer. But still I am stuck with the "yum update" not working. I will post a separate question for that.

Comment: In other words, you don't actually have Internet access. You have access to some subset of the Internet that apparently doesn't include ping.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: ping is never guaranteed. E.g. try `ping microsoft.com` - it will never work, as Microsoft blocks ICMP.

Comment: @mvp Not sure how that's relevant, but yeah.